# Associate an XML-Stylesheet with an XML Document with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

Is it possible to [associate a stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/) with with Nokogiri, to create this structure?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.my-site.com/sitemap.xsl"?>
<root>
  ...
</root>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There is not.

The way I did it:

```
xml.gsub!("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>") do |head|
  result = head
  result << "\n"
  result << "<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"#{stylesheet}\"?>"
end
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

OMG, there is so much fail here that I am breaking the unofficial policy of Team Nokogiri and am providing the correct, sane answer to this question:

```
require "nokogiri"

doc = Nokogiri::XML "<root>foo</root>"
doc.root.add_previous_sibling Nokogiri::XML::ProcessingInstruction.new(doc, "xml-stylesheet", 'type="text/xsl" href="foo.xsl"')
puts doc.to_xml
# => <?xml version="1.0"?>
#    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="foo.xsl"?>
#    <root>foo</root>
```

In the future, please ask questions about Nokogiri on the nokogiri-talk mailing list (http://groups.google.com/group/nokogiri-talk), get the correct answer in a timely fashion, and save everyone a little effort.

Comment: Please also note that the above method has been added to the nokogiri.org tutorial: http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html

Comment: good to see you pop up. It's hard to get every Nokogiri question to use the mailing list, humans being as they are. *I* think it'd be great if there was a way to redirect Nokogiri questions to the list automagically, or at least have them echoed there, but I doubt that will happen either. What's the chance of you and/or Aaron poking your head in regularly?